# Retrieve coordinates of plotted changepoints

Tags: c#, r, data-visualization, r.net

I have plotted Change Points on R as

```
values <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 3 )
values.ts = ts(values, frequency = 12, start = c(2017, 1))
chpoints = cpt.mean(values.ts, method="PELT")
cpts(chpoints)
plot(chpoints)
```

and the plotted graph is

[image]

The `cpts(chpoints)` returns `[1] 4 8`.

**Question 1:** What are `[1] 4 8`?

**Question 2:** How can i get the coordinates of plotted change points, x,y coordinates of the red lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quesion 1: The `cpts(chpoints)` returns vector of segments' end positions. Following your example:

```
plot(chpoints)
abline(v=index(values.ts)[cpts(chpoints)[1]], col="blue") # 4
abline(v=index(values.ts)[cpts(chpoints)[2]], col="green") # 8
```

will add two vertical lines which indicate segment with 'stable' mean. There are no. of segments - 1 change points (`[1] 4 8`) as the last 'change point' is the last value of your time series.

Question 2: Date coordinate for i-th break can be found as:

```
index(values.ts)[cpts(chpoints)[i]]
```

'Stable' mean values are stored here:

```
param.est(chpoints) # 2.50 6.50 2.25
```

I still don't understand why there are white spaces after change points (red lines do not cover the whole time-series). However, if we compute mean values manually:

```
mean(values.ts[1:cpts(chpoints)[1]] ) #
mean(values.ts[(cpts(chpoints)[1]+1):cpts(chpoints)[2]] )
mean(values.ts[(cpts(chpoints)[2]+1):length(values.ts)] )
```

we receive `2.50 6.50 2.25` as above.

Comment: Two things. 1- `index(values.ts)[cpts(chpoints)[1]]` returns 2017.25 and for 2 it returns 2017.583. Both of these values are not part of my x-coordinates. 2- If i multiply my values at y axis then what are the values returned by `cpts(chpoints)` and why `plot(chpoints)` plots no red line?

Comment: 1- Values 2017.25 and 2017.583 are part of your x-coordinates. That's how time is coded time in `ts` function. Check this: `(1:12)*(1:12)`. First month of 2017 is then 2017.0833.

Comment: 2 - `cpts(chpoints)` only indicates Dates when breaks occurred. Number 4 corresponds to 2017.25 . This would not change if you multiply all y values by any non-negative value.Red lines should be between those breaks. But, as I wrote in the answer, I don't understand why it doesn't cover the whole segment.

Comment: How can i define my own custom values on x axis instead of time series?

Comment: Like this: `chpoints = cpt.mean(values, method="PELT")`. x values will be indexed as 1, 2, ..., n

Comment: `cpt.mean` for `values <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 300, 100, 200, 300 )` returns `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11`. What is `[1]` and what is `1,2,3,...` does it mean these values are changing at every index?

Comment: This is really more about R language in general, how R indexes entries in arrays. Unfortunately, I don't have time to go through all this. I believe I've answered both questions asked and after some tweaking, you will find solution soon.